# Text align in div with images having table-cell display attribute

Tags: css, html, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to make the text on top of the div container, but the image is preventing this. I may have review the use of divs may be?

This is the `css`, `html`, `typescript` code:

```
<div *ngFor="let sh of items" style="border: 1px solid; width: 100%; display:table; text-align: center;">
          <div>
            <div style=" width: 20%; display:table-cell">
                <span>{{sh.product.description}}</span>
            </div>
            <div style=" width: 20%; display:table-cell">{{sh.product.price}}</div>
            <div style=" width: 20%; display:table-cell">{{sh.count}}</div>
            <div style=" width: 20%; display:table-cell">{{sh.count * sh.product.price}}</div>
            <div style=" width: 20%; display:table-cell">
              <img src={{sh.product.picture}} style="height: 100%;"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And this is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `vertical-align: top;` to your div

```
<div *ngFor="let sh of items" style="border: 1px solid; width: 100%; display:table; text-align: center;">
          <div>
            <div style=" width: 20%; display:table-cell;vertical-align: top;">
                <span>{{sh.product.description}}</span>
            </div>
            <div style=" width: 20%; display:table-cell;vertical-align: top;">{{sh.product.price}}</div>
            <div style=" width: 20%; display:table-cell;vertical-align: top;">{{sh.count}}</div>
            <div style=" width: 20%; display:table-cell;vertical-align: top;">{{sh.count * sh.product.price}}</div>
            <div style=" width: 20%; display:table-cell;vertical-align: top;">
              <img src={{sh.product.picture}} style="height: 100%;"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```